# console.log changes array length (capacity)

Tags: javascript, arrays, console.log

I'm having a hard time trying to understand why position of console.log() influences capacity of my array. Here's the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/xbqph81e/4/

Here's the code:

```js
const pressed = [];
const secretCode = '123456';

window.addEventListener('keyup', (e) => {
  console.log(e.key);
  pressed.push(e.key);

  console.log("First Log",pressed); //console.log here = array has capacity of 7 characters
  pressed.splice(-secretCode.length - 1, pressed.length - secretCode.length);

  //console.log("Second Log",pressed); //first console.log is commented and this uncommented = array has capacity of 6 characters
});
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Does anyone know why this is happening?

Comment: Because you're using `.splice` to remove one from the array?

Comment: [.splice()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_splice.asp)

Answer (score 0):

In the first `console.log` you've just pushed the new key to the array so at this point it has a length of 7.

After that you call `.splice` to make the array the same length as the secret (in this case 6), so after this point the array will only have a length of 6.

And a `console.log` will *(most times)* display the value of that variable at the point, which happens to be and array with the length of 6.

Answer (score 0):

The `console.log` doesn't change your array.
It is being modified because the `splice()` method changes the array. You can try and use the `slice()` method instead which returns a new array. If you choose to do so, you would need to assign the array that is being returned from `pressed.slice()`.